# c - forked process communicate with sockets

Tags: c, sockets, process, fork

I am trying to to create a socket that communicates with two child processes that have been forked, a and b. I need it to communicate via the socket sc. As a starting point, I am trying to get Process a to write a message to Process b via the sc socket, but so far everything I've tried results in the printing of an error message.

Below is my code. Any ideas on how to finally make it work? (My ultimate goal is to do reading and writing of more than one message, so any advice on that is a definite bonus.) Thanks in advance for any help provided.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main() {
    pid_t a, b;
    int sc;
    struct sockaddr server = {AF_UNIX, "server"};
    sc = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bind(sc, &server, sizeof(server));
    listen(sc, 1);

    if ((a = fork()) == 0) {
        struct sockaddr me = {AF_UNIX, "ProcessA"};
        struct sockaddr there = server;
        int s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        char buffer[256];
        sprintf(buffer, "test");
        if (bind(s, &me, sizeof(me)) < 0) {printf("Error binding\n"); exit(1);}
        if (connect(s, &there, sizeof(there)) < 0) printf("Error connecting\n");
        write(s, buffer, strlen(buffer) + 1);
        printf("Process A\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if ((b = fork()) == 0) {
        struct sockaddr address;
        int length;
        length = sizeof(address);
        int c, n;
        char buffer[256];
        if ((c = accept(sc, &address, &length)) < 0) {printf("Error accepting\n"); exit(1);}
        if ((n = read(c, buffer, 255)) < 0) {printf("Error reading\n"); exit(1);}
        printf("Log Process\n");
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting the messages "error binding" and "error accepting" - Once more, thank you.

Comment: Did you check if the initial calls to `socket`, `bind`, and `listen` before the `fork` succeeded?  I think that you should be using `struct sockaddr_un`, not `struct sockaddr`.  If youre having trouble getting this working, have you considered using `pipe` or `socketpair` rather than a setting up a unix-domain socket?

Comment: Good error messages will help.  Instead of `printf("Error accepting")`, try `perror("accept")`.  Similarly for all of your error messages.

Comment: I added the perror function and am getting the following on the first bind: Address family not supported by protocol family - Do I need to change any of the sockaddr's properties on AF_UNIX or is something else the problem? (I did manage to do this with pipes, now I'm making my way to sockets)

Comment: @user1567060 That probably means that your `struct sockaddr` is not correct.  Try using `struct sockaddr_un` and see the site that I linked in my answer below.

Comment: There's no obvious reason why you need two sockets; one should be sufficient for bidirectional communication between the two child processes.  And having the two sockets is one of the reasons you have problems; it may or may not be the only reason.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: He needs a server socket in one process, and a client socket to connect to it in the other.  What he /doesn't/ need is for the server socket to be shared between the two processes, but I don't think that it does any harm, since he doesn't use it in the client process.

Comment: @user1567060: I just noticed another problem: you're not using `fork` correctly.  You just need to call it once, and it returns twice: once in the original process and once in the child.  You can tell the two apart by its return value; it returns 0 in the child and the child's PID in the parent.

Comment: @nix: read the question.  He requires two children which communicate with each other; there's a supervisory parent process too.  I reserve judgement on the number of sockets needed; I'd need to revisit the manual pages and it is the wrong time of night to be doing that.  You may be right.

Answer (score 5):

From [Beej's Guide](https://beej.us/guide/bgipc/html/multi/unixsock.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sv[2]; /* the pair of socket descriptors */
    char buf; /* for data exchange between processes */

    if (socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sv) == -1) {
        perror("socketpair");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!fork()) {  /* child */
        read(sv[1], &buf, 1);
        printf("child: read '%c'\n", buf);
        buf = toupper(buf);  /* make it uppercase */
        write(sv[1], &buf, 1);
        printf("child: sent '%c'\n", buf);

    } else { /* parent */
        write(sv[0], "b", 1);
        printf("parent: sent 'b'\n");
        read(sv[0], &buf, 1);
        printf("parent: read '%c'\n", buf);
        wait(NULL); /* wait for child to die */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: consider closing the socket you're not using after the fork: `close(sv[0]);` in the child case; `close(sv[1]);` in the parent case.